# Coyping grouped images as picture and crop it in ppt via vba

Tags: vba, grouping, powerpoint, copy-paste, image-size

I have a problem to get a certain amount of shapes in ppt to a certain format. I generate them via nprinting and they are already grouped properly. The problem is that I can´t crop them once their grouped. If they are not grouped I can address each of them individually and crop them the way I want. I need them in picture(u) format in order to be able to crop them. My approach was to cut them and insert them again but as picture. Unfortunately I wasn´t able to cut and paste them via vba with the code below. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

```
Dim myDocument As Object

Set SlidePPT = objPPT.Presentations(FilePPT).Slides(7)
SlidePPT.Select

myDocument.Slides(7).Shapes.SelectAll.Group
Selection.Cut
myDocument.Slides(7).Pictures.Paste

myDocument.Slides(7).Shapes(1).PictureFormat.CropBottom = 200
```

The alternativ I had in mind was to crop it first and Group it then, but this seems not to work either.

edit: Okay, it seems that the problem with my alternative approach is, that my code just selects all of the shapes but does not group them. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. i just needed to add the range.

```
myDocument.Slides(7).Shapes.Range.Group
```